# gsub multiple numerics with a character

Tags: r, gsub

I'm trying to replace a column of multiple numerics with a character

```
[,1]
1
2
3 
4
5
6
```

I have a column of numerics and i want to change *1,2,3* to "**a**" and *4,5,6* to "**b**".

How can I go about with this? 
I can do this:

```
gsub(1, "a", mydata)
gsub(2, "a", mydata)
gsub(3, "a", mydata)
gsub(4, "b", mydata)
gsub(5, "b", mydata)
gsub(6, "b", mydata)
```

But it's very lengthy and I'd like something neater.

I tried `gsub(c(1,2,3), "a", mydata)` but it didn't work.

Another option I found was `chartr("áéó", "aeo", mydata)` but don't think it will work in my case.

Is there a more simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is R.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches to consider, neither of which uses `gsub`:

Sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
vec <- sample(6, 15, TRUE)
vec
# [1] 2 3 4 6 2 6 6 4 4 1 2 2 5 3 5
```

Using `cut`:

```
cut(vec, c(0, 3, 6), c("a", "b"))
#  [1] a a b b a b b b b a a a b a b
# Levels: a b
```

Matching to a predefined dictionary:

```
chr <- c(a = 1, a = 2, b = 3, b = 4, c = 5, d = 6) ## Just as an example
names(chr)[match(vec, chr)]
# [1] "a" "b" "b" "d" "a" "d" "d" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a" "c" "b" "c"
```